# Persistent navbar is flickering

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have made an application on cordova / phonegap with a navbar. 
I have changed the navbar with the css file. With phonegap you can have a
navbar and a header on top of each other. I have changed it with css. (widt
So the first half of the header is a titlebar, and the second half is the navbar.

The html:

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed!important" data-id="header">
    <div data-role="navbar">
    <h3 id="titlebar1"></h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#page_home" data-transition="slide"><h3>Home</h3></a></li>
            <li><a href="#page_zoek_category" data-transition="slide" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist"><h3>Zoek</h3></a></li>
            <li><a href="#page_scan" data-transition="slide"><h3>Scan</h3></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

First I have build this application in phonegap 2.7.0, and the navbar worked great
on my mobile phone (galaxy S4) and tablet (galaxy tab 3 7 inc).

But I wanted to implement new plugins I could only use using cordova 3.0 and higher, 
so I had updated my software. Now the app still works great on my mobile phone, 
but nog on the tablet. The persistent navbar keeps flickering (or reloading).

I know this question is asked before, and I have read the answers, use the `!important`
and yes, i have tried it, and it works, sort of.
When I use the `data-position="fixed!important"` the header isn't flickering, but it is messing up the application. The navbar stays fixed, but the rest of the header, the title bar is dissapearing.

When I test the application on my desktop browser, it shows that the header with is normal, but the height is 0px. So it looks like it is disapearing.

Is there an other way to make my header persisitent instead of `!imortant`?
or maybe another way with `javascript`

Answer (score 0):

Try `data-tap-toggle="false"` on your header, see [documentation](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/api/data-attributes.html)

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rxq09aun/)